# Spring Boot: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am totally new to Spring and started to do the official guides from this site:
https://spring.io/guides

I'd like to do this guide:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

I get the following Exception:

```
2014-02-14 16:25:21.614  INFO 9032 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5b48d763] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2014-02-14 16:25:21.638  INFO 9032 --- [           main] .c.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/work/Spring/SpringTutorial/target/classes/, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-1.0.0.RC1.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-1.0.0.RC1.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/springframework/spring-core/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.0.0.RC1.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.0.0.RC1.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.5/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.5/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.5/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.13/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.0.13/logback-core-1.0.13.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-web-1.0.0.RC1.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.0.0.RC1.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.47/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.47.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/7.0.47/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.47.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/springframework/spring-web/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.3.1/jackson-databind-2.3.1.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.3.0/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.3.1/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar, file:/C:/work/apache-maven-3.0.3/repo/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.2/commons-lang-2.2.jar]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:658)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:355)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:920)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at hu.kumite.Application.main(Application.java:17)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:190)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:163)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
    ... 7 more
```

The application starter class is this:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ScheduledTasks.class, args);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the main method contains a commented line. I've already done a tutorial, namely this one: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/
It's up and running. But I can't run the ScheduledTasks app, which is the following:

```
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledTasks {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        System.out.println("The time is now " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

I use Eclipse and run the Application.java's main as an Application.
Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The scheduling guide isn't a web app so you probably have some mouldy stuff in your pom.xml from the REST guide? If you follow the instructions closely it should work. Another potential issue with the code you posted above is that your `@EnableAutoConfiguration` class is not used in the context, only as a main method (which may not be a problem for the scheduling guide but it probably is for a bunch of others).

Comment: I'm doing all the tutorials into one Eclipse project ending up with one giant pom.
I put it in a seperate project using the pom from the tutorial and now it works perfectly.
Thanks for your help!

What if I want a scheduler in a Spring webapp using this API? I can't do that?

Comment: Of source you can do that. But then you would need all the dependencies for a webapp.

Comment: But then I end up having the Exception which you can see in the thread opening.
Sorry, I think I'm missing something. Should I post the "bad" pom.xml here?

Comment: A "good" pom would have "spring-boot-starter-web" (for convenience) or else all the dependencies included in the starter listed individually. Just check that you have them. Also make sure you include an `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in your `SpringApplication` (the code snippet above does not).

Comment: Works perfectly, I can't thank you enough.

And to get it work I had to add the classes to run in an Object array to SpringApplication's run method :
`SpringApplication.run(new Object[]{Application.class, ScheduledTasks.class}, args);`

Comment: For me the solution was to add the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency to the pom (as mentioned by @Dave Syer), so it would be nice to add this in the accepted answer, if it was the case for @Kumite too so it would be easier to see for others too.

Answer (score 51):

A scan of the `@SpringBootApplication` show that it includes the following annotations:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

So you could do this too:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(ScheduledTasks.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31):

use this one in your pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or this one :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Adding 2 jar worked for me too. I had to use both though

Comment: @FaforeTunde it's not a good sign, take a look at your dependency tree and check if you have used <scope> tag in it.

Answer (score 29):

I had multiple application classes in one Spring Boot project which had the web started included and wanted to avoid it configuring a web environment for one of them so I manually configured it as below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
            .web(false)
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** for Spring Boot 2 and above:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
            .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Try this

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(ScheduledTasks.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

The error suggests that the application you are trying to run cannot instantiate an instance of apache tomcat. Make sure you are running the application with tomcat.

if after checking all your dependencies you experience the same problem, try to add the following in your configuration class

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = 
                  new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    return factory;
 }
```

If you are using an external instance of tomcat (especially for intellij), the problem could be that the IDE is trying to start the embedded tomcat. In this case, remove the following from your pom.xml then configure the external tomcat using the 'Edit Configurations' wizard.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Great answer! It solved my issue. However it was working in intellij. When I created the jar using the maven shade plugin, the same classpath was created so I don't really understand what happened.

Answer (score 18):

Add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 8):

if you experience this exception while using intellij and you are trying to start the application with the `run` button. Try starting the application from the command line instead. E.g. ensure that you are in the correct directory (directory with your pom file) assuming this is a `springboot` application run `mvn spring-boot:run` this did the trick for me.

Additionally I have also seen this error occur when your spring application depends on another application. In this case I had to start the other application first then run.

Comment: Restarting IntelliJ (Ultimate 2016.3 here) fixed it for me

Comment: In addition to the Marquis given solution above, I made sure I chose the right version of mvn and jdk combination to run the `mvn spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 6):

Adding the annotation `@SpringBootApplication` Before the starter class fixed this problem for me (so in essence, this error message can mean "you don't have a `@SpringBootApplication` marked class anywhere, you need at least one)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppStarter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppStarter.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've had similar problems when the main method is on a different class than that passed to SpringApplcation.run()

So the solution would be to use the line you've commented out:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you package it as a single jar and it's non web app try to load app context as below.

```
@SpringBootApplication

ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Main.class);
```

Or use below plugin to package as a single jar

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

you can specify the external configs by using below command to run

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

/http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlboot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Note that if you are passing the properties as arguments then don't include `@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")` it will override the parameters

Comment: Adding the spring-boot-maven-plugin and <phase>package</phase> and then running app as mvn clean package worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you run it successfully using command line `gradle bootRun`, while packaging it with command line `gradle jar` to jar file in order to run it with command line `java -jar build/libs/demo.jar`, unfortunately, it failed with Exception: `Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean`, in this case, you need to use task `bootRepackage` of gradle plugin `spring-boot` to generate special runnable jar.

- setup 1

  > $ gradle clean bootRepackage
- setup 2

  > $ java -jar build/libs/demo.jar

Comment: I have no idea why, but `gradle clean bootRepackage ` helped me. Previously, I have manually clean all cache and build folder.

Answer (score 2):

A `SpringApplication` will attempt to create the right type of `ApplicationContext` on your behalf. By default, an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` or `AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext` will be used, depending on whether you are developing a web application or not.

The algorithm used to determine a ‘web environment’ is fairly simplistic (based on the presence of a few classes). You can use `setWebEnvironment(boolean webEnvironment)` if you need to override the default.

It is also possible to take complete control of the `ApplicationContext` type that will be used by calling `setApplicationContextClass(…​)`.

[Tip]
It is often desirable to call `setWebEnvironment(false)` when using `SpringApplication` within a JUnit test.

Comment: How do you use setWebEnvironment when creating the application via `SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);`?

Comment: @tgdavies see my answer above, you can use the `SpringApplicationBuilder`

Answer (score 2):

Adding the spring boot starter dependency fixed my error.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This is required if you want to start the tomcat as an embeded server.

Answer (score 2):

check your pom.xml is exists

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I've had a problem like this；For lack this dependency

Comment: This fixes my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case we **added the @Profile annotation newly** in order to ignore the TestApplication class in production mode and the Application class in test mode.

Unfortunately, we forgot to add the following line into the application.properties files:

```
spring.profiles.active=test
or
spring.profiles.active=production
```

Without these config no profile was loaded which caused the not-so-much saying Spring Error.

Comment: I'd like to add that you can also get this error if you provide both the @Profile annotation and pass the profile to the jvm.

Answer (score 1):

This should be caused by dependency issue, in general, you need to check the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The problem it's in this class:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    SpringApplication.run(ScheduledTasks.class, args);
    }
}
```

The correct way to launch your application is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Clear repository** is one possible solution.

Windows -> delete all subfolders in the maven repository:

> C:\Users\YourUserName.m2\repository

Comment: To anyone following the PluralSight tutorial on Java Spring, this is the only solution that worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I have stuck with same problem. As I didn't define Main.class and the following annotations in Spring-Boot using Maven:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you missing **@SpringBootApplication** in your spring boot starter class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LoginSecurityAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoginSecurityAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is exclusion of starter tomcat, I tried exclude it and use vert.x, so when I integrate wit Spring Admin, started problems

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this Exception in the following situation.

in my POM was properties:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <!-- The main class to start by executing java -jar -->
    <start-class>com.scmaer.java.microservice.Application</start-class>
    <cxf.version>3.1.5</cxf.version>
    <olingo.version>2.0.10</olingo.version>
    <spring.boot.version>1.4.7.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <spring.boot.plugin.version>1.5.8.RELEASE</spring.boot.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
</properties>
```

and the name and path of my application class ("start-class") was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the problem was a broken maven repo jar file. In my case, the `tomcat-embed-core` jar file was broken. So I removed it from the maven repo and refreshed it to download again.

Comment: ]Please use formatting tools to properly edit and format your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happen after excluding the resource folder from the `pom` using the following code.

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*/*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
</resources>
```

Commenting this code started my code.

Answer (score 0):

An other cause of this problem is corruption of maven repository jars so you can use the following command to solve the problem :

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using gradle, met seem issue when I have a commandLineRunner consumes kafka topics and a health check endpoint for receiving incoming hooks. I spent 12 hours to figure out, finally found that I used mybatis-spring-boot-starter with spring-boot-starter-web, and they have some conflicts. Latter I directly introduced mybatis-spring, mybatis and spring-jdbc rather than the mybatis-spring-boot-starter, and the program worked well.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case, spring configurations were not loaded as expected. On running from cmd using below command, it worked:

```
start java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m <and the usual parameters as needed, like PrintGC etc> -Dspring.config.location=<propertiesfiles> -jar <jar>
```