# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletException

Tags: spring-boot, junit4, spring-boot-test

when i am trying to run the controller Testing in Spring-boot version 1.5.3 Release using the Spring-Boot-Test I am geting the Error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletException

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.hanselnpetal.domain.CustomerContact;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ContactsManagementControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    ContactsManagementController contactsManagementController;

    @Test
    public void testAddContactHappyPath() {

        CustomerContact aContact = new CustomerContact();
        aContact.setFirstName("Jenny");
        aContact.setLastName("Johnson");

        // POST our CustomerContact form bean to the controller; check the outcome
        String outcome = contactsManagementController.processAddContactSubmit(aContact);

        // Assert THAT the outcome is as expected
        assertThat(outcome, is(equalTo("success")));
    }


}
```

I am running the class ContactsManagementControllerIntegrationTest.java  using (eclipse) the  right click on the file and run as junit . any help appreciated.

Comment: do you have servlet api in dependencies? are you user maven or gralde?

Comment: yes  I am using the maven and spring-boot-web-stater which download the spring-boot-starter-tomcat\1.5.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
D:\mavenrepo\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.14\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar
D:\mavenrepo\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\8.5.14\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.14.jar
D:\mavenrepo\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\8.5.14\tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.14.jar

Comment: do you have servlet api with provided scope?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have below dependency in your pom.xml (maven)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.

Comment: for that refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783391/spring-boot-unable-to-start-embeddedwebapplicationcontext-due-to-missing-embedd